# Inserting react code based on postMessage between two wordpress pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, window-object

In wordpress  I am clicking a search button in `front-page.php` , that calls a result page .  `front-page.php` loads `FrontPage.js` , which has this:

```
  localStorage.clear();
  localStorage.setItem('flightCardsDataArray', JSON.stringify(flightCardsDataArray));
  isDataLoaded();
  window.postMessage({ type: 'flightCardsDataLoaded', data: flightCardsDataArray }, '*');
```

I would like to read this message in `App.js` , which is React code and this react code insert cards on result page . In `App.js` I am doing this

```
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'flightCardsDataLoaded') {
    // Data has been sent from the search page
    const data = event.data.data;
    console.log('flightCardsDataArray - from app', data);
  }
});
```

but it always gives me `data` , which is associated with the previous search. I would like to get data for the current search (latest click on search button of `front-page.php`) .

**UPDATE**
As per suggestion below , I set the debugger and see that correct iteration of data is passed in `flightCardsDataArray` when I set it in `localstorage`, however I am still not able to figure out why `App.js` shows previously passed data.

My guess is that `App.js` is reading the message even before the latest click happens , but how do I resolve this? Or is there any other way to approach this?

Comment: Looks like you're using the postMessage API correctly, I suspect `flightCardsDataArray` is not what you expect it to be when it's passed. I would stick a debugger in there an walk through the code. Also check out your local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the approach and made the API call in React itself. So , when the button is clicked in `front-page.php` , it goes to `result page.php` which is rendered by React . So I made the call to API in React just before rendering hence eliminating the need for event listeners to listen from one page to another to transfer data.

The data that needs to be passed from `front-page.php` to `result page.php` and do not require event listeners can still be passed using `localStorage.setItem` and get it in react using localStorage.getItem . Here is what I am doing in react application which includes fetching and parsing data

```
const CreateApp = (props) => {

  //use useState (https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) for handling asynchronous behavior

  const [card, setCard] = useState([]);
  const [cardLoaded, setCardLoaded] = useState(false);
  const fetchCardData = async () => {
    try {
   
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://yourapi.com/method',
        params: {
          param1: '1',
          param2: localStorage.getItem('param2'),
          param3: localStorage.getItem('param3'),
        },
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
          'Some-Key': 'abc',
          'Some-Host': 'yourapi.com'
        }
      };

         const response = await axios.request(options);
         
       //parse response
        return parsedResponse ;
    } catch (error) {

      console.error('Error occurred while parsing , error);
      return { success: false };
    }
  }

 //useEffect for rendering with asynchronous response (https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect)

  useEffect(() => {
     // Call the fetchCardData function to fetch data
     fetchCardData()
       .then((parsedResponse) => {
          
         // Now you have the parsedResponse, you can set it in your state or use it as needed
         setCard(parsedResponse);
         setCardLoaded(true);
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error('Error occurred while fetching data:', error);
       });
   }, []);


if (!cardLoaded) {
  return <p>Loading...</p>;
}
  //render with data
  const columns = card.map((item, index) => {
 return(
 <div className="col-lg-4 responsive-column">
  ....
  .... 
 </div>
    );
 });
     
return <>{columns}</>;

}
export default CreateApp;
```